# Как сделать в реакте textarea (web-forms) с изначально введеным словом?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Как сделать в реакте textarea (web-forms) с изначально введеным словом hello?и после него должен стоять курсор

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730896/2118955

Answer (score 0):

Так не?

```html
<textarea>Hello</textarea>
```

Comment: Нет. Так https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html раздел textarea tag